# Static variable for each extended class

Tags: java, inheritance

Let's say I have a base/main `abstract` class: `AbstractObject`. `AbstractObject` is extended by two classes: `Object1` and `Object2`.

Those two templates have many different classes extending from them also, for instance, `Object3`, `Object4`, and `Object5` are inheriting from `Object1`, and `Object6`, `Object7` are inheriting from `Object2`.

I want each separate class (`Object1`, `Object2`, ..., `Object7`) to have a counter that counts the number of instances made of it.

I thought I could use some `public static` variable `counter`, but I am not sure how to declare it in `AbstractObject`, so none of my objects will copy the code. Any thoughts?

```
abstract class AbstractObject {
  ...
  public static counter = ?
}

class Object1 extends AbstractObject {
  ...
}

class Object2 extends AbstractObject {
  ...
}

class Object3 extends Object1 {
  ...
}

class Object4 extends Object1 {
  ...
}

class Object7 extends Object2 {
  ...
}
```

Comment: You can't. Each class needs to have its own counter field (why should it be public?). Or you can use a single shared CountManager which would use some Map<Class, Integer> containing the count of each class.

Comment: That said, why do you want to count instances of a class? What concrete problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want a separate counter for each object (i.e. 3 `Object1`, 2`Object2`, etc.), and NOT a counter that counts how many of every type has been made in total (i.e. 20 Objects)?

Comment: @JBNizet Exactly, a different counter for each different class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want ... to have a counter that counts the number **of instances**
>   made of it.

Instances - that mean "objects instatiated for each class" ?
If yes, then use a static map. For example:

```
public class AbstractObject {

    private static Map<Class, Integer> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());

    public AbstractObject() {
        Class clazz = this.getClass();
        map.merge(clazz, 1, (x, y) -> x + y);
    }

    public static Map<Class, Integer> getCounters() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Object1 extends AbstractObject {
}
```

---

```
public class Object11 extends Object1 {
}
```

---

```
public class Object2 extends AbstractObject {
}
```

---

```
public class Object12 extends Object11{
}
```

---

And now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AbstractObject o1 = new Object1();
    o1 = new Object1();
    o1 = new Object2();
    o1 = new Object11();
    o1 = new Object11();
    o1 = new Object12();

    AbstractObject.getCounters().forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " ==> " + v));
}
```

gives this result:

```
class somepackage.Object11 ==> 2
class somepackage.Object12 ==> 1
class somepackage.Object1 ==> 2
class somepackage.Object2 ==> 1
```

Comment: Yes, and you could use an abstract method that each class would have to implement to get its own record count from the static map.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a static field `count` in each class. If we have a static field only in `AbstractObject` class, it will NOT be inherited to other classes (because it is static).

To count the number of objects of each class, you have to use a "factory" method (like `getNewInstance()` in below example).

```
public abstract class AbstractObject {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object1 a = Object1.getNewInstance();
    Object2 b = Object2.getNewInstance();
    Object2 c = Object2.getNewInstance();

    System.out.println("Number of Object1 instances = " + Object1.getCount());
    System.out.println("Number of Object2 instances = " + Object2.getCount());
  }
}

class Object1 extends AbstractObject {
  private static int count;

  private Object1() {
  }

  static Object1 getNewInstance() {
    count++;
    return new Object1();
  }

  static int getCount() {
    return count;
  }
}

class Object2 extends AbstractObject {
  private static int count;

  private Object2() {
  }

  static Object2 getNewInstance() {
    count++;
    return new Object2();
  }

  static int getCount() {
    return count;
  }
}
```