# overriding static methods in C++

Tags: c++, overriding, static-methods, static-members

I have a base class `Character`, that can `Attack()`, and derived classes `Magician`(10), `Elf`(5) or `Giant`(15).
Magicians can evolve to  `BlackMagician`(15)

each type of `Character` has a defined `Power`(in parenthesis). My question is how to associate a class with a static function `getFamilyPower()` and overrride it, accordingly.

The code is below:
https://codecollab.io/@sdudnic/warriors

The idea is the following:

```
class Character {
    static int power;
public:
    static int getPower() { return power; }
    virtual int Attack(Character *other) { /*...*/ }
};

class Magician : public Character {
    static int power = 10;
public:
    static int getPower() {return power; }
};

class Elf : public Character {
    static int power = 5;
public:
    static int getPower() {return power; }
};

class Giant : public Character {
    static int power = 15;
public:
    static int getPower() {return power; }
};
```

Comment: Please show the code, instead of just describing it.

Comment: I don't know if I got that right, but it sounds to me like you either want Character.Attack() to be virtual or have a member Character::power that gets set by your derived classes and used by Character.Attack().

Comment: You can only override a virtual function, so no static.

Comment: How should a static function with no parameters know which instance is used?

Comment: @Surt he's talking about overriding, not overloading

Comment: my idea is to have a static member `power` in each class, and return that power in `getPower()` static function

Comment: @cigien I added the code please review my question

Comment: Thanks, that's much better :) I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @Serge why are you so keen on using `static`? I don't think you understand what `static` really does. It is not going to work in your situation, especially when you take evolution into account.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, is somthing similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962095/static-variable-for-each-extended-class where each class has its own "number"

Comment: @Serge that is a completely different situation, and that solution doesn't apply to your situation. Even if you ignore your requirement to support per-character evolutions (which prevents you from using a `static` number for evolved entities), you would still need a non-static virtual method in order to return the per-character numbers in a polymorphic manner correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Only `virtual` methods can be overridden. But a `static` method cannot be `virtual`, as it has no `this` instance pointer from which to access a vtable.  So each `Character` will need a non-static `virtual` method to report its current power level, eg:

```cpp
class Character
{
public:
    int health = 100;

    void Attack(Character *other) {
        int myPower = Power();
        int theirPower = other->Power();
        if (theirPower > myPower)
            health -= theirPower;
        else if (theirPower < myPower)
            other->health -= myPower;
    }

    virtual int Power() = 0;
    virtual void Evolve() {}
};

class Magician : public Character
{
public:
    bool isBlack = false;

    int Power() override { return isBlack ? 15 : 10; }

    void Evolve() override { isBlack = true; }
};

class Elf : public Character
{
public:
    int Power() override { return 5; }
};

class Giant : public Character
{
public:
    int Power() override { return 15; }
};
```

Comment: so, can I have a variable used with "return myStaticVar"

Comment: I added the code, based on your one, thanks, please review the question

Comment: Yes you CAN override non-virtual methods (included static) in C++. The only thing you lose is polymorphic dispatch -- i.e., the compiler has to know the exact type at compile time. i.e. which `Power()` method to call would have to be known at runtime in the above examples so it does work in this use case.